# Регулярные выражения Python - ограничения на похожий паттерн

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо с помощью регулярных выражений из текста достать числовые данные опираясь на определенные слова.

Есть 2 строки: 1 строка дана в полноценном виде и на него, написанное ниже, регулярное выражение работает так, как нужно. Вторая строка похожа на первую, но в ней нет некоторых данных и необходимо, чтобы одно и то же регулярное выражение обрабатывало 2 эти разные строки правильным образом.

```
str1 = """
СРВ

Правый

точка1

1.1

1.2

1.3

точка2

2.1

2.2

2.3

Левый

точка1

1.4

1.5

1.6

точка2

2.4

2.5

2.6

"""

str2 = """
СРВ

Правый

точка1

1.1

1.2

1.3

Левый

точка1

1.4

1.5

1.6

точка2

2.4

2.5

2.6

"""

pattern = 'СРВ.*?Правый.*?точка2\n*([\d\.]*)\n*([\d\.]*)\n*([\d\.]*)'

search1 = re.search(pattern, str1, re.S)

"""Достали 3 числа из первой строки после "Правый" и "точка2". Все работает корректно."""

if search1:
    print(search1.group(1), search1.group(2), search1.group(3) )
```

Во второй строке у "правого" нет "точки2" и необходимо, чтобы поиск вернул пустые значения, но он перепрыгивает на "Левый" к "точке2" и берет значения оттуда. Как сделать ограничение, чтобы не перепрыгивал на похожий паттерн ниже, значения которого уже здесь не нужны?

```
search2 = re.search(pattern, str2, re.S)

if search2:
    print(search2.group(1), search2.group(2), search2.group(3) )
```

Comment: Если задача в том, чтобы использовать именно регулярные выражения, попробуйте воспользоваться чем-то вроде [онлайн тестера регэкспов](https://regex101.com/). Полезная вещь. Имеет лаконичную справку по возможным токенам и объясняет все совпадения. А вообще, при первой же возможности я бы изменил формат входных данных на, например, json, который парсится стандартным модулем в 1-2 строки. А с регэкспами, имхо, слишком много шаманства.

Comment: Да, абсолютно с Вами согласен. Просто изначальный формат данных вообще docx и даже XML из него разобрать не получается. Поэтому вытаскиваю из него текст, а потом уже через регулярки. А json - вообще сказка бы была.

Comment: Во втором случае, я так понимаю, вообще не должно быть совпадения. Ведь нет точки 2 в Правом.

Comment: В общем, попробуйте https://regex101.com/r/rxyisb/1